# Android Studio randomly disappear some UI after few minutes uses

Tags: android-studio, user-interface

Android Studio disappear randomly UI.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BTDV.png)
Every time disappear randomly button, text, windows and more.
In my android studio four plugins. Was installed Matherial UI, but i deleted it.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQieg.png)

I tried disable any plugins, but nothing happened.

Comment: Try doing `"File" > "Manage IDE Settings" > "Restore Default Settings"`. 
This should reset the settings.